# how to get glut.h file in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, mingw-w64

I am self-learner in Qt. I trying to learn 3D programming with QT. I wanted to leaern glut.h libraries in `OPENGL`. In my windows pc, I am using `MinGW` compiler. In compiler GL path : `(Z:\Qt\qt-4.8.6-x64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\GL)`

Although I include `LIBS += -lglut`  there is no glut.h file.

inside GL path there is only such files:

```
 Directory of Z:\Qt\qt-4.8.6-x64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\GL

02.06.2015  19:00    <DIR>          .
02.06.2015  19:00    <DIR>          ..
21.12.2014  11:40            45.301 gl.h
21.12.2014  11:40             6.858 glaux.h
21.12.2014  11:40           208.391 glcorearb.h
21.12.2014  11:40           723.325 glext.h
21.12.2014  11:40            10.310 glu.h
21.12.2014  11:40            41.836 glxext.h
21.12.2014  11:40            42.638 wglext.h
               7 File(s)      1.078.659 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  36.618.063.872 bytes free
```

How can I import and use `glut.h` it?

**EDIT:**

according to Erik Man's responce I downloaded glut rar in my computer. When I add glut.h in GL/ folder. QT says `:-1: error: cannot find -lglut`
in .pro line;

```
LIBS += -lglut   (also -lglut32 not working)
```

I think I need to add 3 files for using glut libraries, (correct me if I am wrong) files are :

```
glut.h in "/include/GL"
libglut32.a in "/lib/"
glut32.dll in "windows/system32/"
```

however in downloaded glut rar I couldnt find `libglut32.a`  and `glut32.dll`

Comment: Are you try `LIBS+=-lglut32` ?

Comment: @HienNgo  it is not about including path in .pro file. There is no glut libraries inside GL folder.

Comment: Have you *installed* GLUT? And the `-lglut` is just a linker flag to tell the linker to link with the specific library, it says nothing about any header files.

Comment: You can find glut here: https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/ (glut is not part of the OpenGL standard)

Comment: @ErikMan I am not very good about installing libraries, could you be more specific? for windows x64 MinGW  how can I install it correctly without any problems in my Qt and mingw enviroment

Comment: @goGud just looked closer, it might not be possible to get it running with Qt, glut is a wrapper for making it easier to write programs on multiple platforms, similar to QtGui (but glut is _much_ simpler). So if you want to use Qt it is probably better to skip glut.

Comment: @ErikMan however, I see samples in youtube and they are using glut libraries in QT

Comment: @goGud can you post a link?

Comment: @ErikMan you can see it after 7:40 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nzHSkY4K18

Comment: @goGud they are using just the built in objects of glut, not the window system part. I think you need to compile glut yourself, there is a guide here: http://www.joshuaburkholder.com/glut/ and here http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/glut

Comment: @ErikMan thank you for your effort, link is very old there is no files inside documentation.. I tried to compile another glut libraries for creaeting dll however I also failed.